# IsNumber for currency type?

Tags: formula

Can I check if only number is entered in currency field for fields like Accounts.Potential_value to verify using ISNUMBER function?

I am getting Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNUMBER() when used with currency.

Comment: Currency field by default accepts only numbers.. you need not have additional validation rule on top of it

Comment: I am guessing there is a validation rule on that currency field which is causing that error. remove that validation rule and give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Check [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISNUMBER) - purpose is to see if digits are entered into a text field

```
ISNUMBER(sometextfield)
```

only takes text fields as argument - not currency which are decimal fields

> Validation Rule Example:

```
OR(LEN(Bank_Account_Number__c) <> 10,
NOT(ISNUMBER(Bank_Account_Number__c)))
```

> This validation rule ensures a
>   custom text field called Bank Account Number is a number of 10 digits
>   and is not blank.